# Qt5: Sql queries failing and tables not shown

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite, qt5, qtsql

There are many similar questions on here already but unfortunately, none has solved my problem so far.

I am stuck connecting Qt to a simple sqlite database. The connection can be established, but queries fail with `No query Unable to fetch row` and `db.tables()` returns me no tables.

My code is the following:

```
void DBManager::connOpen()
{
    m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    m_db.setDatabaseName(m_db_path);
    m_db.open();

    if (!m_db.open())
    {
        qDebug("Error: Connection to database failed.");
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug("Connection to database established.");
        QSqlQuery query(m_db);
        query.prepare("SELECT * FROM data1");
        if (!query.exec())
        {
            std::cout << query.lastError().text().toStdString() << std::endl;
            std::cout << query.executedQuery().toStdString() << std::endl;
        }
        while (query.next())
        {
            std::cout << query.value("id").toString().toStdString() << ". " << query.value("one").toString().toStdString() <<  std::endl;
        }

        QSqlDriver *driver = m_db.driver();
        QStringList tables = m_db.tables();
        std::cout << "tables found: " << tables.count() << std::endl;
        for(QString table: tables)
        {
            QSqlRecord record = driver->record(table);
            std::cout << "name: " << table.toStdString() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "count: " << record.count() << std::endl;
            std::cout << record.fieldName(0).toStdString() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This leads to console output like this:

`Connection to database established.
No query Unable to fetch row
SELECT * FROM data1
tables found: 0`

My database should have one table (data1). Executing the query by hand returns this:
[image: executing query in console]

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: For simple sql query without bind variable, instead of `prepare`, try `query.exec("SELECT * FROM data1")`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just figured out what was wrong: I was using a sqlite2 database with a sqlite3 driver the whole time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came down to a very stupid mistake.

I was using a sqlite2 database that I created using `sqlite mydb` while `QSQLITE` is the driver for sqlite3 (using `sqlite3 mydb`).

Comment: Ah, I forgot those time constraints :)